# Incorrect answer when using literal value vs. computed value in C

Tags: c, function, double, return, literals

First let me say that this is my fourth day learning C, so forgive me if my code is not as clean and concise, but I believe it gets the job done. Also, I wanted to practice writing all of the math functions because I felt I would benefit more if I wrote them myself. My compiler is GNU gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

I ran into this bug when I wrote a function to convert degrees to radians. When I coped the radian value for 15 degrees into my source code, I got the **correct** answer. I then wrote the function to convert degrees from radians, used it to get the radian value for 15 degrees, and plugged it into to my sin(x) function, and it returned an **incorrect** value.

I then tested a lot of different scenarios to try and debug my code (as you can see with all the *printf*s). I then printed the value (to 54 decimal digits) of my **computed** radian value and **copied** that number into my source code... the answer came up correct.

So my question is: In what scenario would using a computed value differ than using that same computed value, but copied directly into the source code?

I understand that the compiler will automatically cast any literal values if they are not of the same type as the parameter that the function takes, but in my case, I don't understand how it differs.

Here is the code. Again, sorry if its a big sluggish, but hey, this is for learning purposes only :)
Any help would be appreciated, I just can't wrap my head around what could cause this, and my 4 hours of research has led nowhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define EPSILON 0.000001
#define PI 3.14159

double sin(double x);
int fact(int x);
double powr(double x, int power);
double deg_to_rad(double degrees);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    double radian = deg_to_rad((double)15);

    printf("Correct answer = 0.25881883\n\n");
    printf("Sin approximation using constant .26179917: %1.8f\n\n", sin(.26179917));
    printf("Radian variable calculated by deg_to_rad(15): %1.54f\n", radian);
    printf("Sin approximation using radian variable: %1.8f\n\n", sin(radian));
    printf("Sin approximation using radian variable's value (0.261799166666666638381144593950011767446994781494140625) copied and pasted into source: %1.8f\n", sin(0.261799166666666638381144593950011767446994781494140625));

    return 0;
}

double deg_to_rad(double degrees){

    return ((degrees/180) * PI);
}

double abs_val(double x){

    if (x < 0){
        return (-x);
    }

    else{
        return x;
    }
}

int fact(int x){

    if (x > 1){
        return (x * fact(x - 1));
    }

    else return 1;
}

double powr(double x, int power){

    if (power < 1){

        if (power == 0){
            return 1.0L;
        }

        else{
            puts("This functionality is not yet built in to this function.");
            return 0.0L;
        }
    }

    else if (power > 1){
        return (x * powr(x , power - 1));
    }

    //If power is 1.
    else return x;
}

/*
* Based on the Taylor series: sin(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! + x^9/9! - ... +  (-1)^(n-1)*x^(2n-1)/(2n-1)! + ....
*/
double sin(double x){

    static int n = 0;
    n++;

    double result = (powr(-1.0L,n - 1) * (powr(x, (2*n - 1)) / fact(2*n - 1)));

    //If the current n is odd.
    if (n % 2){

        if (abs_val(result) > EPSILON){
            return (result + sin(x));
        }

        else {
            //Reset n and now begin returning from recursions.
            n = 0;
            return result;
        }
    }

    else {

        if (abs_val(result) > EPSILON){
            return (-result +  sin(x));
        }

        else {
            //reset n and now begin returning recurstion
            n = 0;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend indenting your code properly (3 or 4 spaces for each level)... it'll make it MUCH easier to reason through!

Comment: Define "correct". You're not gonna get 54 digits of precision out of `double`.

Comment: Also watch out for destructive cancellation in your series summation and integer overflow in your factorial function.

Comment: I don't understand why you are printing 54 digits of precision, when you are only using Pi to 5 decimals.

Comment: Rename your `sin` to `sine`. I suspect with the literal value, the compiler evaluates it at compile time using the built-in function. Or compile with `-fno-builtin`.

Answer (score 3):

The call `sin(constant)` is evaluated at compile time with the built-in sine function, not your `sin`. If you compile with the `-fno-builtin` flag, or rename your function, your code is used to compute the value for the constants too, and yields the same (wrong) result.

The wrong result is due to

```
if (abs_val(result) > EPSILON){
    return (-result +  sin(x));
}
```

in case of even `n`. The sign is already incorporated into `result`, so that should be `return result + sin(x)` too, like for the case of odd `n`. And thus both branches (should) contain exactly the same code, hence the branch should be removed.

Further, the factorial will overflow when its argument is larger than 12 (for signed 32-bit `int`s), thus your `sin` function will not work for arguments of large absolute value that would require more than six terms to reach the desired accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Daniel's tips, I would not set `EPSILON` to a precision level higher than your estimation of `PI`. Well, they are independent, but you'd be calculating a really accurate `sin` for an imprecise degree to radian conversion.

Here's a little more compact version of your code:

```
static double r_sin(double xx, double term, int n, double result) {
    double r = term * xx/(2*n * (2*n+1));
    if (r > EPSILON) {
        if (n % 2) return r_sin(xx, r, n+1, result-r);
        return r_sin(xx, r, n+1, result+r);
    }
    return result;
}

double my_sin(double x){
    if (x > EPSILON) return r_sin(x*x, x, 1, x);
    return 0;
}
```